# How to Create Mulitple xml files separately from an input xml file containing multiple xmls in it

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

Take AllFile.xml as an input and produces four output xmls.The size of the input file is greater than 100MB.

Input xml File(AllFiles.xml):-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <canonMessage xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="">
    <header>
    </header>
    <trailer>
    </trailer>
    </canonMessage>
    //some raw strings
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <canonMessage xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="">
    <header>
    </header>
    <trailer>
    </trailer>
    </canonMessage>

    //some raw strings
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <canonMessage xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="">
    <header>
    </header>
    <trailer>
    </trailer>
    </canonMessage>

    //some raw strings
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <canonMessage xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="">
    <header>
    </header>
    <trailer>
    </trailer>
    </canonMessage>
```

Expected Output:-
1) file1.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <canonMessage xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="">
    <header>
    </header>
    <trailer>
    </trailer>
    </canonMessage>
```

2)file2.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <canonMessage xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="">
    <header>
    </header>
    <trailer>
    </trailer>
    </canonMessage>
```

3)file3.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <canonMessage xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="">
    <header>
    </header>
    <trailer>
    </trailer>
    </canonMessage>
```

4)file4.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <canonMessage xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="">
    <header>
    </header>
    <trailer>
    </trailer>
    </canonMessage>
```

Provide the java utility or any third party utility accessible from java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, This might not be the best approach. I have just showed to an example. Writing to the file should be done as per the requirement.

```
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
           String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                         "<canonMessage xmlns=\"\" xmlns:xsi=\"\">\n" +
                         "<header>\n" +
                         "</header>\n" +
                         "<trailer>\n" +
                         "</trailer>\n" +
                         "</canonMessage>\n" +
                         "//some raw strings\n" +
                         "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                         "<canonMessage xmlns=\"\" xmlns:xsi=\"\">\n" +
                         "<header>\n" +
                         "</header>\n" +
                         "<trailer>\n" +
                         "</trailer>\n" +
                         "</canonMessage>\n" +
                         "\n" +
                         "//some raw strings\n" +
                         "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                         "<canonMessage xmlns=\"\" xmlns:xsi=\"\">\n" +
                         "<header>\n" +
                         "</header>\n" +
                         "<trailer>\n" +
                         "</trailer>\n" +
                         "</canonMessage>\n" +
                         "\n" +
                         "//some raw strings\n" +
                         "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                         "<canonMessage xmlns=\"\" xmlns:xsi=\"\">\n" +
                         "<header>\n" +
                         "</header>\n" +
                         "<trailer>\n" +
                         "</trailer>\n" +
                         "</canonMessage>";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(<\\?xml)([\\s\\S]*?)(>)([\\s\\S]*?)(<\\/canonMessage>)" );
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher( xml );

    int iteration = 0;
    while( matcher.find() )
    {
        String fileStr= matcher.group( );
        System.out.println( fileStr );
        System.out.println( "\n\n" );
        BufferedWriter writer;
        try
        {
            writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter ( "file" + iteration + ".xml") );
            writer.write( fileStr );
            writer.flush( );
            writer.close();
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        iteration++;
    }
}
```